# Creating custom list for survey - High priority

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, infopath, html-editor

I wanted to create a custom list with set of questions and table. It should work like a survey form. where people can only answer and submit the form.

I have tried survey option in sharepoint, which will not allow the user to insert any table.

Pls give me some suggestions. High priority

Comment: Stop reposting the same question

Answer (score 0):

not true, if you set the field as rich text it allows you to draw sharepoint tables